# How do I pass data from a ListView object in a fragment to an Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment

I'm a beginner in working with fragments in Android, I haven't done any code on what I'm asking about, since I lack a little bit of knowledge in Fragments. I have not found any tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: Seriously you couldn't find any tutorial? This is very hard to believe. Try Google.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the object a [Parcelable](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html) object. Then you can send the object from fragment to activity or vice versa using [Bundle](https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

For passing data to another activity you can use
`intent.putextra("key","value");`. Even it is an object you can put in place of value but object should be made extends parcable.

And in the activity use

```
String val = getintent.getStringExtra("key")
```

If object change likewise.

You can put lots of putextra if needed before calling `startactivity(intent)`.

Comment: I can define a variable as a String that gets the data(text), and instead of putting "value" i put that fariable